# Piecewise linear function in high dimension

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Suppose we have a concave function $f(x):[0,+\infty)^d\rightarrow [0,+\infty)$ which is nondecreasing. In addition, define another piecewise linear function as $g(x) = \sum_{i\in \{i|x_i \leq \bar{x}_i\}} \lambda_i\cdot x_i + \sum_{i\in \{i|x_i > \bar{x}_i\}} \lambda_i\cdot \bar{x}_i: [0,+\infty)^d\rightarrow [0,+\infty)$, where $\bar{x}$ is a fixed point and $\lambda$ is the parameter I want to design. The only constraint for $\lambda$ is to make $g(\bar{x}) = f(\bar{x})$, i.e. $\sum_{i\in[d]} \lambda_i \cdot \bar{x}_i = f(\bar{x})$

My question is: is it possible to design a function $g(x)$ with appropriate $\lambda$ such that $g(x) \leq f(x)$ for any $x$ while ensuring $g(\bar{x}) = f(\bar{x})$? The answer is very intuitive in 1 dimension, we can simple set $\lambda = \frac{f(\bar{x})}{\bar{x}}$, and $g(x) = \frac{f(\bar{x})}{\bar{x}} \cdot x$ if $x\leq \bar{x}$ and $g(x) = f(\bar{x})$ if $x > \bar{x}$, which is shown in the following figure:[image]

But in high dimension,it seems the task is more intricated, I've tried with $\lambda_i = \frac{f(\bar{x})}{\bar{x}_i \cdot d}$. In this case, although $\sum_{i\in[d]} \lambda_i \cdot \bar{x}_i = f(\bar{x})$ is true, but I wasn't able to prove $g(x') \leq f(x')$ for any $x' \neq \bar{x}$.

---

Update: $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere. By non-decreasing, I meant every element in $\nabla f(x)$ is greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: If $d>1$, what do you mean by "$f(x)$ is nondecreasing"?

Comment: I meant the gradient is non-negative, like $\nabla f(x)$ is greater than or equal to zero in every dimension.

Comment: The gradient is a vector. What do you mean when you say that a vector is greater or equal to zero? There is no natural order in $R^d$ when $d>1$.

Comment: in every dimension, I meant. In other words, $\nabla f(x) [i] \geq 0$, for every dimension $i \in [d]$.

Comment: I don't understand your terminology and notation.

Comment: Okay, sorry about the confusion. Here, I suppose the function domain is $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then the gradient of $f(x)$, which is $\nabla f(x)$ is a vector of length $d$. By nondecreasing, I meant every element in the vector $\nabla f(x)$ of length $d$ is greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115356/discussion-between-francis-and-uniquesolution).

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable? Because if not you could still require that $f$ is nondecreasing in all input variables $x_i$.

Comment: yes, I assume $f$ is differentiable everywhere. I've updated the problem statement.

Comment: Are the functions $f,g$ defined in $\Bbb R^d$ or $[0,\infty)^d$?

Comment: Good point, it should be $[0, +\infty)^d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we remove the condition that $f$ is differentiable,
then a counterexample can be found
(instead of defining nondecreasing via the gradient, we would need to define it
by requiring that $f$ is nondecreasing in every variable $x_i$).

I believe even if $f$ is differentiable you will encounter similar problems.

Let $d=2$, $f(x)=\min(x_1,x_2)$, $\bar x=(1,1)$.
Suppose that there is a $\lambda$ such that $g$ satisfies the requirements.
Then we would have
$$
\lambda_1 = g((1,0)) \leq f(x) = 0
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lambda_2 = g((0,1)) \leq f(x) = 0.
$$
This implies
$$
g(\bar x)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2 \leq 0 
$$
which is a contradiction to $f(\bar x)=g(\bar x)$
and $f(\bar x)=1$.

Comment: Nice example! Any intuition why we have this problem in high dimension but not in the single dimension?

Comment: @Francis Not sure, but concavity is a property on a line segment, maybe that could play a role.